# How to give values in SqlParameter[] method in EFCORE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
 public int ExcuteStoreProc(string query, SqlParameter[] Parameters)
    {
        return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, Parameters);
    }
```

Above attached is my method in my class, now I want to call this method in my services class. So whenever I call it this way:

```
 _colDeptAccessRepository.ExcuteStoreProc("CloneDeptPermissions", 
                new [] 
                {
                    new SqlParameter("newDepartment",dept.ID),
                    new SqlParameter("oldDepartment",deptDto.DeptId),
                });
```

It throws error saying : The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects. Please help me how can I execute a method call.

Comment: Please note:
My stored procedure doesn't return anything.

Comment: That code is fine.  Your problem is elsewhere.  Try to post a complete repro and you'll probably find the problem.

Comment: `SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];

                param[0] = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@newDepartment",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Value = depId
                };
                param[1] = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@oldDepartment",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Value = deptDto.DeptId
                };

                dynamic response = ExecuteScalar("CloneDeptPermissions", param);`

Comment: This code is working but the question code isn't

Comment: Please don't paste code into comments.  Edit the question to include a short, complete repro of the issue.

Comment: There are few few reasons for issue 1)The parameter names are lower case upper case sensitive.  Make sure the names are correct.  2) Does the Server have more than on Database.  The default database may be wrong.  You can either add the database name in the connection string or in you query add "Use database_name"  3) Make sure you added the stored procedure properly.  See : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx 4) Do other queries work?  Try a simple Select query to make sure you have the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient iso System.Data.SqlClient.

So add this using statement:

```
  using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
```